How are the feet established in inverse kinematics?
So, I'm working on a game in Unity, It was a 3D game. and I was intending that the player character uses inverse kinematics and prodedural animation, and stuff like that. To be clear they don't have a human-like rig or structure. But the problem is that I don't really know how to encode the feet to be atatched to the ground when the player is touching it, and to detach when they are not. Are there any possible solutions I could try? I tried to implement a raycast feature that allows the body to detect if they're toughing the ground or not, but I couldn't go on from that point. Again, any possible solutions would be nice.

Have you tried using unity's built in IK system? I'm pretty sure it dones't require humanoids.

There are tons of tutorials on this subject. Here is an example to start you off: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jfKTmEWJESw&ab_channel=NickMaltbie
